# M-V-VM WPF: Way to maintain Databinding while passing parent object of Databound object into IValueConverter?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, ivalueconverter

I'm using model-view-viewmodel I currently have a class with 3 pieces of data: 2 integers and an enumeration.

Its constructor looks like this:

```
//C#
public Outcome(OutcomeEnum outcomeEnum, Int32 acutalOutcomeData, Int32 expectedOutcomeData)
{
  m_outcomeEnum = outcomeEnum;
  m_actualData = acutalOutcomeData;
  m_expectedData = expectedOutcomeData;
}
```

I have 2 ComboBoxes next to each other that I have bound to one List of outcome objects (`List<Outcome>`)  which I use to the "actual" and "expected" integer values.

This section of code  looks like this: (The SelectedItem and ItemsSource are dependency properties in the viewmodel )

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OutcomeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedExpectedOutcome, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="PART_cbExpectedOutcome" Grid.Column="1" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=ExpectedOutcomeData, Converter={StaticResource OutcomeDataToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=Expected }" />  
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OutcomeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActualOutcome, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="PART_cbActualOutcome" Grid.Column="2" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=ActualOutcomeData, Converter={StaticResource OutcomeDataToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=Actual}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

*My problem is:* I'd like to pass a reference to the Outcome object into the IValueConverter that I'm using to convert between, but this appears to not be possible using the IConvertParameter but rather I would be forced to use Multibinding per the [msdn post here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9f3e4f6d-20d2-4c13-90a2-7c157ed4f8c3/).

I'd like to simplify my approach as creating a multibinding for something relatively as simple as this seems like overkill.

I'd like to do only one thing with the Outcome object that I seek to pass into IValueConverter, which is to determine the enumeration type of OutcomeEnum so I can provide the proper formatting of the expected or actual data value.

Is there any simpler way for me to be able to pass the Outcome object into the IValueConverter `OutcomeDataToStringConverter` while maintaining a two-way binding with this list of Outcome objects? I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For right now, I ended up changing the Outcome class so it had only one member - outcomeData

Then I created two lists of Outcome objects which were bound to the combobox's ItemsSource - ActualOutcomeList and ExpectedOutcomeList.

I can then bind the Outcome object itself to the Combobox, but by having two lists I avoid the duplicate selection issue I describe in the comment on Avaid's post.

In the end the code looks like this:

```
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource OutcomeToStringConverter}}" />  
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

</ComboBox>

<ComboBox 
    x:Name="PART_cbActualOutcome" 
    Grid.Column="2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActualOutcomeList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedActualOutcome, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsOutcomeEnabled}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource OutcomeToStringConverter}}" />

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you bind to the entire `Outcome` object instead of its `ActualOutcomeData` or `ExpectedOutcomeData` properties? That way the converter will receive the entire `Outcome` object, and based on it and on the converter parameter return the proper value.

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource OutcomeToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=Expected}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: That is a good idea, the first thing I tried. The issue is that if I bind the Outcome object on both comboboxes, if I have only one list of Outcome objects *both* comboboxes will be synchronized to the same object. In practice this means when I change one combobox it can change the value of the other combobox, e.g. you have 3 items in the list with actual/expected equal to 1/1, 2/2 and 3/3. If you change combobox 1 to 2, BOTH show 2/2, when i really want 2/1.

Comment: I believe you should achieve separation in the selection of the combo boxes by setting IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to false... Please let me know if that's not the case.